# Reflection Method.getParameterTypes()‬ - array of objects parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to get all methods parameters names.

The problem is when one of the parameters is of type:  the.package.myobject []  (array)

```
String name = method.getParameterTypes()‬[0].getName()
```

I get: [the.package.myobject;]  //letter L and symbol ;

how can I get pure type name? (without substringing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check `type.isArray()` and, if yes, use `getComponentType()`.

```
final Class<?> c = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
final String name = (c.isArray()? c.getComponentType() : c).getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what you want is

```
Class firstType = method.getParameterTypes()‬[0];

// will be null if not an array.
Class firstComponentType = firstType.getComponentType();
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo, please see my post again.